# What does the mozdisallowselectionprint attribute in PDF.js do?

Tags: firefox, printing, selection, pdf.js, printing-web-page

Firefox' built-in PDF viewer, [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), has a `mozdisallowselectionprint` attribute on the `<html>` tag. What does this attribute do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `mozDisallowSelectionPrint` attribute was added to Firefox to allow web pages to disable the *print selection* option in Firefox.

Normally, when you select text in a document and then open the print dialog  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), you can choose the option "Selection" under  "Print range".

Because of the way PDF.js works, selecting this option when viewing a PDF document would either result in empty pages being printed or, for large documents, a browser crash.

In bug [830278](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=830278) it was therefore decided to allow web pages, including the PDF viewer, to disable the option to print selections by adding this attribute to the `HTML` tag..

[image: Print dialog with the option to print a selection disabled.]
<sub>(source: [broward.edu](https://bconline.broward.edu/shared/Tutorials/Students/Resources/PrintingContent/browserprintdialog.png))</sub>

`mozDisallowSelectionPrint` is available from Firefox 19 and onwards.